# Как передать пакеты из Input цепи в Output используя netfilter?

Tags: linux, ip

Здравствуйте!
Задача состоит в том, чтобы получить пакет, затем заменить IP назначения, и отправить пакет на новый адрес, используя neftilter, nftables и nf_queue.
В настоящее время мы получаем пакеты, отправляем их в userspace с помощью nf_queue и изменяем их dest IP, а вставить новые пакеты в Output цепь, чтобы отправить их не получается.

Comment: Может все же такие пакеты надо отправлять не в OUTPUT, а в POSTROUTING (см. в [вике](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter)).

Comment: prerouting если быть точным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

согласно [wiki nftables](http://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Performing_Network_Address_Translation_(NAT)) для переброски пакетов, приходящих, к примеру, на 80 и 443 порты интерфейса eth0, надо ввести такие команды:

```
$ sudo nft add table nat
$ sudo nft add chain nat prerouting { type nat hook prerouting priority 0 \; }
$ sudo nft add chain nat postrouting { type nat hook postrouting priority 0 \; }
$ sudo nft add rule nat prerouting iif eth0 tcp dport { 80, 443 } dnat ip-адрес-назначения
$ sudo nft add rule nat postrouting masquerade
```

ну и, конечно, не забыть разрешить forwarding пакетов:

```
$ echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```